# Rails 4.1 locale and 'version' based on url (.com, .cz, .de, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hope somebody can point me at the right direction with this...

Basically, i have the locales setup and it works fine. However, i need to depending on how the user gets to the site (example_company.com, example_company.cz or example_company.de..) have slightly different content(views and layout).

I've managed to boil it down to a constant or env variable that if i was to run multiple instances of the site(1 for each country), i could set on the server so that i get the behaviour i need with 1 code base.

My question is, how are people dealing with this in general? is there any way i can serve all countries on the same instance and set some flag based on .com or .cz or whatever, that dictates which 'version' they get without effecting the url itself?

I already have the locales in the url and would prefer not to mix the two as i will have to support multiple languages for each version. For example, french and czech would still support english.. But if i go to the french one, i will only show 2 locales (french and english)...

Hope i managed to explain properly.. if not let me know and i will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Rails' built-in i18n support, you can easily select locales by TLD.

From the official [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-domain-name):

> One option you have is to set the locale from the domain name where your application runs. For example, we want www.example.com to load the English (or default) locale, and www.example.es to load the Spanish locale. Thus the top-level domain name is used for locale setting. This has several advantages:
>
> - The locale is an obvious part of the URL.
> - People intuitively grasp in which language the content will be displayed.
> - It is very trivial to implement in Rails.
> - Search engines seem to like that content in different languages lives at different, inter-linked domains.
>
> You can implement it like this in your ApplicationController:

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_tld || I18n.default_locale
end

# Get locale from top-level domain or return nil if such locale is not available
# You have to put something like:
#   127.0.0.1 application.com
#   127.0.0.1 application.it
#   127.0.0.1 application.pl
# in your /etc/hosts file to try this out locally
def extract_locale_from_tld
  parsed_locale = request.host.split('.').last
  I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(parsed_locale) ? parsed_locale : nil
end
```

Be sure to read the [i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.htm) in full. It covers how to use the built-in i18n support. A big advantage is you don't need separate views for each locale.

Comment: I see what you're saying.. The issue is that the locales need to work as they are.. the idea is that locales will have nothing to do with the 'version'(domain) requested. They will simply behave as translation options. i just want to pass a flag to a before_action that will dictate which version to display. You answer does not answer my question exactly BUT part of it. By using the extract_locale_from_tdl function on a before_action to determine the contry, i'm able to chose with version to server. Thanks a lot!